# What's the best way to substitute a different "close window/tab" keyboard shortcut for CTRL-w?

Tags: ubuntu

I've looked at the "`Keyboard Shortcuts`" settings under `System->Preferences` and under the sectino called "`Window Management`" there is a "`Close Window`" setting which is mapped to ALT+F4 by default.

However that does not serve quite the same function as `CTRL+w` which closes a tab.

I also looked in `gconf-editor` to try to find where `CTRL+w` is defined but can't find it under the `metacity/global keybindings` section.

Does anyone know where this is defined and how it can be changed? I need to be able to close a tab with a single keypress. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not finding it, because this feature is application specific.  There is a general convention that CTRL+W is the close function, but it's not editable in metacity and it's not even universally applicable.  In `vim` you type `:close` for example.

If you have a specific application you want to perform this action on, maybe someone will have an answer.

**Update**

Grawity provided an outstanding comment.  There is a gconf setting that when set to true, allows the user to dynamically type a new accelerator when positioned over an active menuitem.  Not all applications support this.  For example there are a lot of bug reports complaining about [evolution mail ignoring this flag](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libbonoboui/+bug/20010).

If you want to do this yourself, you can open a terminal and type:

```
gconftool-2 -type bool -set /desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels true
```

Comment: Many GTK applications allow rebinding shortcuts for menu items: enable it in `gconf:/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels`, then just hilight a menu item and press the new shortcut.

Comment: What's an accelerator?

Comment: Sorry - an accelerator is another term for 'keyboard shortcut'